# How can I pass / paste multiple variables in Automator as text in Google Chrome

Tags: applescript, automator

Creating an cal event application that runs every day and asks for my self reported happiness and stress levels. Having issues with the final applescript, which I can't make work no matter what I try. The closest I got was with

[here's a basic layout of what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rM3uR.png)

I know this might be basic, so I very much appreciate everyone's help!

```
on run {input, parameters}
set hello to item 1 of input as text
tell application "System Events" to keystroke hello
end tell
return input

end run
```

---

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention exactly what you are going to be doing with the values in these variables, but you can get the value of your workflow variables by name in the AppleScript action, for example:

```
value of variable "Happy" of front workflow as text -- or integer, or whatever
```

Note that the **Set Value of Variable** action will output the variable value, which in this case will be used by the following **Ask for Text** action, so you can use the **Ignore Input** option to keep the previous results from being used.  Your example workflow would then be something like:

- **Ask for Text**  { Question: *Happy (1-10)* }
- **Set Value of Variable** { Variable: *Happy* }
- **Ask for Text**  { Question: *Stressed (1-10)* } (Ignore Input)
- **Set Value of Variable** { Variable: *Stressed* }
- **Run AppleScript** (note that the variables are coerced to text when joining to other text):

  ```
  on run {input, parameters}
    set happyString to "Level of happiness: " & (value of variable "Happy" of front workflow)
    set stressedString to "Level of stress: " & (value of variable "Stressed" of front workflow)
    display dialog happyString & return & stressedString
  end run
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this AppleScript code will work for you, without having to add variables to your Automator workflow

```
property numberList : {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

set happyNumber to (choose from list numberList ¬
    with title "Happiness And Stress Levels" with prompt ¬
    "Choose Your Happiness Level" default items 5 ¬
    OK button name "Continue" cancel button name ¬
    "Cancel" multiple selections allowed false ¬
    without empty selection allowed) as integer

if happyNumber is 0 then return
set happyLevel to "Your Happiness Level Is " & happyNumber

set stressNumber to (choose from list numberList ¬
    with title "Happiness And Stress Levels" with prompt ¬
    "Choose Your Stress Level" default items 5 ¬
    OK button name "Continue" cancel button name ¬
    "Cancel" multiple selections allowed false ¬
    without empty selection allowed) as integer

if stressNumber is 0 then return
set stressLevel to "Your Stress Level Is " & stressNumber

(* Just Un-Comment The Next 2 Lines When You Are Ready To Use Them *)

--tell application "System Events" to keystroke happyLevel
--tell application "System Events" to keystroke stressLevel
```